# How to make my footer appear after die()

Tags: php, html, footer

HTML HEADER CODE HERE

```
<div id="content">
<?php
$checkvars = array('subject','message');
foreach ($checkvars AS $checkvar) if (strpos($_REQUEST[$checkvar],'{php}')!==false) die("We are sorry, but you cannot use \"{php}\" in a ticket submission. If you do have a legitimate issue, please press the back 
button in your browser and then change any instances of \"{php}\" to \"(php)\" so that your ticket may be submitted. Keep in mind that in the event that you are trying to exploit our system, we log and report all hack attempts to IC3.GOV.");
?>
</div>
```

HTML FOOTER CODE HERE

I am using the above code for a billing system to stop the exploit of eval through support ticket submissions. The header is working fine, but the footer will not show up (because of the die command i assume). I have very little knowledge of coding (I didn't write the above code, it was wrote by someone else that shared it on another website) and was hoping someone could help me get my footer to appear.

Comment: There's no coming back from the dead. Use `break` instead.

Comment: I would suggest that if you find something wrong with the submitted information you simply print out your footer or whatever and then use die();

Comment: The answer is to not `die`. You'll have to restructure your application to fail differently.

Answer (score 0):

Create your own function like this

```
died($message)
{
    //call footer
    die($message)
}

//Use it like this

died('You did something wrong');
```

Comment: This'll put the message underneath the footer. Try this: `function died($message){ echo $message; call_footer(); die(); }`.

Comment: @JosephSilber That code didn't work bud. All it did was return a blank page.

Comment: @Isaiah - Of course not. You have to actually create the `call_footer` function!

Answer (score 0):

YOU CANT!

You asked the script to die right now - so how are you supposed to output code after that

[Sounds like the CS issues I got many years ago when a customer complained their database was closed badly after the machine lost power - because only I can write that special code that runs when the machine is off to neatly close the tables]

Comment: C has the `atexit` function, so maybe OP was looking for something similar.

Comment: Sounds more like he is trying to find a solution to a problem that doesnt exist. die() is not a normal code path - and really shouldnt ever happen on production code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php) to define a function that will run when `die()` is called before the script dies.

Alternatively, you could just replace the `die()`s in your code above with a function that calls `die()` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Doing any serious work "inside" the HTML is a bad structure to begin with. Do all your validation, database queries, file operations and so on **before** you begin any output of any sort.

```
<?php

// check $_POST
// update the database
// validate data
// water the plants
// DECIDE WHAT THE USER SHOULD SEE

?>
<html>
...
</html>
```

If you detect any error or invalid action, you can simply output a complete error page. An architecture that emphasizes this a lot is MVC, where *controller logic* and *views* are clearly separated. Try to learn from that structure.

Answer (score 0):

IC3.gov is the reason Advanced Currency Markets got shut down in Switzerland.